# Udev rule runs, script fails

Tags: linux, udev, yocto

I am trying to use udev to detect a USB attach event then run a script. There are many examples of this but I can not seem to get it to work.

My script is `/usr/bin/` is very plain `usbattached.sh`

```
!/bin/bash

echo !Hello World!
mkdir /media/usb_device
mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb_device
```

My rule in /etc/udev/rules.d is also very simple `usbconnected.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0243", RUN+="/bin/usbattached.sh"
```

I have reset the device many times in hopes udev would update. So far it has not. I also attempted to run a command to refresh the rules with no luck.

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

Is there something wrong with my rule/script?

Plugging my USB into my device I get the output

```
root@imx6ull14x14evk:/usr/bin# [  344.348033] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  347.572148] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[  347.796563] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0243, bcdDevice= 0.02
[  347.805120] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  347.820492] usb 1-1: Product: STORE N GO
[  347.829885] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[  347.839204] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 12050602000042
[  347.864925] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

Edit: I did  give my script executable permissions with `chmod +x usbattached.sh`

Edit 2: turning on udev debug and watching the journctl. I remove and add my USB device. I see in the log

```
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: 1-1: /etc/udev/rules.d/usbconnected.rules:1 RUN '/bin/usbattached.sh
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: 1-1: Running command "/bin/usbattached.sh"
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: 1-1: Starting '/bin/usbattached.sh'
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 275.
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: 1-1: Process '/bin/usbattached.sh' failed with exit code 1.
Mar 03 15:44:00 imx6ull14x14evk systemd-udevd[270]: 1-1: Command "/bin/usbattached.sh" returned 1 (error), ignoring.
```

This means my script is running, but erroring out.

Answer (score 1):

> `!/bin/bash`

Your bash shebang is malformed (first character should be `#`). Also, `udev` will only run scripts with `sh`, not `bash`. The first thing you should do is fix the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`.

> `echo !Hello World!`

1. `!` is a special character so you need to quote the string that contains it, otherwise it will get interpreted by the shell. (ex.: `echo '!Hello World!'`
2. The script will not be run in an interactive shell by `udev`, so `echo`'d text will not appear anywhere. If you want confirmation the script is being run, redirect it to a file: `echo '!Hello World!' > /tmp/output_$(date +%s).txt` (the `$(date +%s)` part gives the file a unique name each time the script is run).

Answer (score 0):

Moving the script to `/home/michael` solved the issue. I assume this has to do with user privilege's.

I am using a terminal to act as root during development. Running the command as myself in `/usr/bin` works as expected. I assume udev runs as a user that does not have root permissions.

Comment: `udev` runs as root but will only run scripts with `usr/bin/sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Why do my scripts fail to run from /etc/udev/scripts ?